# Нужно ли создавать WebApp телеграм боту на Pythonanywhere?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

Бот прописан в scheduled tasks на pythonanywhere. Но спустя сутки бот перестаёт работать. Вызвано ли это тем, что я не создал WebApp для данного бота, ибо бот не использует Django или Flask ?

Comment: pythonanywhere sometimes refresh consoles, so your bot will not be working. Also polling is not the best way to keep bot running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Да](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/148/), **нужно**.

> Тот бот, который у вас есть сейчас, просто работает внутри консоли под вашим редактором. На самом деле он будет работать довольно долго, но если PythonAnywhere выполнит какую-либо работу по обслуживанию системы, требующую перезапуска сервера, на котором он работает, он остановится и не перезапустится. Это явно не очень хорошо для бота, так что давайте исправим это.
>   То, что мы будем использовать, это API-интерфейс Telegram "webhooks". Webhooks - это другой способ подключения к Telegram. Наш предыдущий код установил исходящее соединение из PythonAnywhere с Telegram, а затем полагался на то, что Telegram отправляет сообщения по этому соединению для обработки. С веб-крючками все наоборот. По сути, мы говорим Telegram,
>   - "когда мой бот получит сообщение, подключитесь к PythonAnywhere и передайте сообщение". Делается это всё через вебприложения, используя Flask/Django/bottle...